# How to obtain profile confidence intervals of the difference in probability of success between two groups from a logit model (glmer)?

Tags: r, logistic-regression, lme4, confidence-interval

I am struggling to transform the log odds ratio profile confidence intervals obtained from a logit model into probabilities. I would like to know how to calculate the confidence intervals of the difference between two groups.

If the p-value is > 0.05, the 95% CI of the difference should span from below zero to above zero. However, I don’t know how negative values can be obtained when the log ratios have to be exponentiated. Therefore I tried to calculate the CI of one of the groups (B) and see what the difference of the lower and the upper end of the CI to the estimate of group A is. I believe this is not the correct way to calculate the CI of the difference because the estimate of A is also uncertain.

I would be happy if anyone could help me out.

```
library(lme4)    
# Example data: 
set.seed(11)
treatment = c(rep("A",30), rep("B", 40))
site = rep(1:14, each = 5)
presence = c(rbinom(30, 1, 0.6),rbinom(40, 1, 0.8))
df = data.frame(presence, treatment, site)

# Likelihood ratio test 
M0 = glmer(presence ~ 1 + (1|site), family = "binomial", data = df)
M1 = glmer(presence ~ treatment + (1|site), family = "binomial", data = df)
anova(M1, M0)

# Calculating confidence intervals
cc <- confint(M1, parm = "beta_")
ctab <- cbind(est = fixef(M1), cc)
cdat = as.data.frame(ctab)

# Function to back-transform to probability (0-1)
unlogit = function(y){
    y_retransfromed = exp(y)/(1+exp(y))
    y_retransfromed
}

# Getting estimates
A_est = unlogit(cdat$est[1]) 
B_est = unlogit(cdat$est[1] + cdat$est[2])
B_lwr = unlogit(cdat$est[1] + cdat[2,2])
B_upr = unlogit(cdat$est[1] + cdat[2,3])

Difference_est = B_est - A_est

# This is how I tried to calculate the CI of the difference
Difference_lwr = B_lwr - A_est
Difference_upr = B_upr - A_est

# However, I believe this is wrong because A_est is also “uncertain”
```

**How to get the confidence interval of the difference of the probability of presence?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can calculate the average treatment effect in the following way. From the original data, create two new datasets, one in which all units receive treatment A, and one in which all units receive treatment B. Now, based on your model estimates (in your case, `M1`), we compute predicted outcomes for units in each of these two datasets. We then compute the mean difference in the outcomes between the two datasets to get our estimated average treatment effect.  Here, we can write a function that takes a `glmer` object and computes the average treatment effect:

```
ate <- function(.) {
  treat_A <- treat_B <- df
  treat_A$treatment <- "A"
  treat_B$treatment <- "B"
  c("ate" = mean(predict(., newdata = treat_B, type = "response") -
    predict(., newdata = treat_A, type = "response")))
}
ate(M1)
#        ate 
# 0.09478276
```

How do we get the uncertainty interval? We can use the bootstrap, i.e. re-estimate the model many times using randomly generated samples from your original data, calculating the average treatment effect each time. We can then use the distribution of the bootstrapped average treatment effects to compute our uncertainty interval.  Here we generate 100 simulations using the `bootMer` function

```
out <- bootMer(M1, ate, seed = 1234, nsim = 100)
```

and inspect the distribution of the effect:

```
quantile(out$t, c(0.025, 0.5, 0.975))
#        2.5%         50%       97.5% 
# -0.06761338  0.10508751  0.26907504
```

Comment: First of all, thanks for the great answer.  I have still some questions about it: 
a) Do I have to worry about the warnings, or is this just owed to the fact that the treatment effect cannot be evaluated with only one treatment in the sample data? I am particularly concerned about the one saying that the model failed to converge.

Comment: warnings() (i) 1: In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  ... :
(ii)   unable to evaluate scaled gradient
(iii) 2: In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  ... :
(iv)    Hessian is numerically singular: parameters are not uniquely determined
(v) In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  ... :
(vi)   Model failed to converge with max|grad| = 0.0157858 (tol = 0.001, component 1)

Comment: b) Is this procedure called a “parametric bootstrap?”
c) Can I calculate the p-value as follows:  `p_value = mean(abs(out$t - mean(out$t))>= abs(out$t0))`
d) Is there no way to get a profile confidence interval (i.e. a CI based on a likelihood ratio test) on the treatment effect on the probability of presence?

Comment: (a) I wouldn't be too worried about the convergence warnings if they are only occurring for a handful of runs. You can also refer to more in-depth discussions of `lmer`/`glmer`'s convergence warnings on SO and elsewhere on the web. (b) Yes. (c) I think your method makes sense, but I'm not absolutely sure. (d) Sorry, I'm not familiar with the profile method.

Comment: Thank you Weihuang Wong! I will accept this answer, but I will still be happy to hear from others ...